# Nokogiri parsing for metawords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I know this question has been asked earlier but I am not able to get the parsed result. I am trying to parse metawords using nokogiri, can any one point out my mistake?

```
keyword = []
meta_data = doc.xpath('//meta[@name="Keywords"]/@content')                                         #parsing for keywords
meta_data.each do |meta|
  keyword << meta.value
end
key_str=keyword.join(",")
```

I tried running this in irb as well but keyword returns a nil.

This is how I used it in irb

```
 require 'rubygems'  
 require 'nokogiri'
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML("www.google.com")
```

have already tried alternatives from other stackoverflow posts like
[Nokogiri html parsing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442237/nokogiri-html-parsing-question/3442302#3442302)  but of no use, they still return nil. I guess i am doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer over here work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442237/nokogiri-html-parsing-question/3442302#3442302 This may be a repost of that question.

Comment: @Devin I have already tried that.. it returns nil as well. I have tried all possible solutions.

Comment: @noobie You have not "tried all possible solutions". That's a silly, impossible, melodramatic thing to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. www.google.com does not have any meta keywords in the source. View Source on the page to see for yourself. So even if everything else went perfectly, you'd still get no results there.
2. The result of `doc = Nokogiri::HTML("www.google.com")` is

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
   <html><body><p>www.google.com</p></body></html>
   ```

   If you want to fetch the *contents* of a URL, you want to use something like:

   ```ruby
   require 'open-uri'
   doc = Nokogiri::HTML( open('http://www.google.com' ) )
   ```
3. If you get a valid HTML page, and use the proper casing on `keywords` to match the source, it works fine. Here's an example from my IRB session, fetching a page from one of the apps on my site that happens to use `name="keywords"` instead of `name="Keywords"`:

   ```ruby
   irb(main):001:0> require 'open-uri'
   #=> true
   irb(main):002:0> require 'nokogiri'
   #=> true
   irb(main):003:0> url = "http://pentagonalrobin.phrogz.net/choose"
   #=> "http://pentagonalrobin.phrogz.net/choose"
   irb(main):04:0> doc = Nokogiri::HTML( open(url) ); nil # don't show doc here
   #=> nil
   irb(main):005:0> doc.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]/@content').map(&:value)
   #=> ["team schedule free round-robin league"]
   ```

Comment: thank you for the solution... as it turns out it was indeed a silly mistake on my end small k and yes that was a wrong statement to make "all possible solutions" instead of " many solutions "